# Xamarin iOS - enable Save button based on data validation result

Tags: validation, events, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a following problem, which I am not sure, how to solve. I am building app's setting, where user can specify list of accounts (left `TableViewConstoller`). As you can see on the screen, there is a `Save` button, which stores new account into the database.

Everything works, except for empty `Name` value, which cause an exception. I need to solve it in way, where `Save` button would be enabled only if data pass validation (`Name` is not empty).

I was thinking about some event, which would monitor `Account.Name` property and based on it's value, `Save` button would be enabled/disabled.

Problem is, that I have no idea, how to achieve that.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data to pass validation it would need an event to be triggered first, so why don't you simply hook into the touchupinside event of the 'save' button perform some validation against the data that is being submitted and if it fails display an alert to the user? Seems like a cleaner approach to me, which would also include visual prompting. otherwise you would need the button to be set to disabled from the start and then perform a check every time one of the tableviewcells is interacted with.

The validation would be fairly simple: (obviously use an '&&' operand to validate against more than one empty textbox)

```
If(nameTextBox.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
{  
     // Great store the data
}
else 
{ 
     UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView () { 
          Title = "alert title", Message = "this is a simple alert"
     };
     alert.AddButton("OK");
     alert.Show ();
}
```

If you have a code example I may be able to be more specific.

Edit:

It's also worth considering your future requirements, should you be able to handle no name being passed, if the user doesn't have one already stored should you force them to supply one, or if the user already has a name and passes through no name change, should you simply keep the existing name and proceed to update all of the other fields that the user may have interacted with. It always pays to take some time to architect out your requirements for any given feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Digitalsa1nt. Actually I've already used this approach, but still as a workaround. You are right that this is probably correct approach as well. Originally I wanted to have similar behavior as in iOS calendar - Add button is not enabled unless you add even name.
Anyway, thanks a lot for this solution.

Comment: Anytime, I'm glad you came to the same conclusion, good luck with the app building.